# PHP find if file in different top folder exists

Tags: php, file, quotes

What i want to do is find if a file in a different top folder exists.

Lets say I want to access the file `this "page".html`, I would have to access it like:

```
file_exists('../data/pages/this "page".html')
```

But that wont work, it just returns false. Any suggestions?

i am making a flat file cms, so filenames can have quotes. url: http://ffcms.comxa.com/admin
user: tann98
pass: pswd

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The file you want to access doesn't actually have quotes in the name does it??

Comment: @Mala: no error. just file_exists return false. @JMC Creative: it can. what i am making is a flat file cms. so it CAN have the quotes in it.

Comment: Nope. not in safe mode. You can check the Apache settings here: http://ffcms.comxa.com/admin/info.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
file_exists('../data/pages/this%20"page".html');
```

**%20** for **space** character

**file_exists** works on the file system and not via HTTP. So **%20**  will not be recognized as space but literally as **%20** use spaces instead:

Answer (score 0):

and be sure to use dirname(**FILE**) to really start from the right folder - this is important if your function call is in an included file ...

```
file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/pages/this page.html')
```

Comment: everything is in the root. `dirname(__FILE__)` returns a server path.

Comment: Really? hmm... didnt work for me, though. its trying to access `/home/a1160843/public_html/admin/../data/pages/More "Stuff".html`     edited post, by the way...